# Remote access Ubuntu Server filesystem through GUI

Tags: server, filesystem, gui, remote-access

I recently installed Ubuntu Server on an old computer to test various things.

For now, I always accessed the server through ssh in a powershell/cmd session in my win10 laptop.

How can I access the Ubuntu files through with a GUI?

For the moment I just know accessing it through ssh with for example FileZilla.

I also could install (is one built in?) a ftp server an access it.

But what are the ways I could access ubuntu server files with a GUI "out-of-the-box" without needing to install anything?

Comment: Umm... [Nautilus](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/nautilus-connect.html.en)?

Comment: Do you mean from Windows? Without installing anything in Windows? Or do you mean from Ubuntu (an Ubuntu desktop system)? If from Windows, maybe Samba (in Ubuntu) would be an alternative, see for example https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba  ; If from Ubuntu, Nautilus (using ssh) is a good alternative, as suggested by @pomsky.

Comment: Thanks sudodus & pomsky I mean without installing anything in ubuntu server. Accessing from Linux & Windows. @sudodus if you post an answer I accept it :)

Comment: TotalCommander can access a remote filesystem through SSH, sort of like sshfs on Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Ubuntu server

When you write that you do not want to install anything in the Ubuntu server, I guess you mean except an SSH server, which you have already (for example `openssh-server`) or a Samba server according to this link and links from it,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba)

---

If you want to log in and run application programs remotely, you can do it via

```
ssh user@ip-address
```

or if you want to run GUI application programs remotely,

```
ssh -X user@ip-address
```

if you have some basic X software installed in the server, for example

```
sudo apt-get install fluxbox xinit xterm
```

and the software you want to run.

### From Windows

If you do not want to install anything into Windows, Samba is a good alternative. You can use Explorer and connect to the Samba share like you would connect to a shared directory in another Windows system via the network.

But there are several tools, that can be installed, and that communicate via ssh, not only Filezilla, but also WinSCP. You can also install an SSH client and log in.

### From Ubuntu Desktop

If you do not want to install anything into an Ubuntu Desktop system, Nautilus is a good alternative. It can connect via ssh, enter the address into the box for directory to be displayed, for example `sftp://sudodus@192.168.0.2/home/sudodus` and you can save it as a bookmark for easy access later.

And as described earlier, you can run

```
ssh -X user@ip-address
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **sshfs**, i uses ssh an no need to extra software.
Project source from github: https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win

Its avaiable on Windows, linux and mac. You can take a look in this video https://youtu.be/lMC5VNoZFhg?t=547

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Webmin](https://webmin.com/), which has a [File Manager](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/HTML_File_Manager) module.

Setup Webmin repos:

```
sudo curl -o setup-repos.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webmin/webmin/master/setup-repos.sh
sudo sh setup-repos.sh
```

Install Webmin:

```
sudo apt install webmin
```

Then Webmin can be accessed on the IP address of the host on port 10000 (`https://X.X.X.X:10000/`).